# Unable to view data collected in mongoDB using hygieia-feature-jira-collector in Hygieia UI

Tags: hygieia

While configuring the Feature widget in Hygieia UI for JIRA, Project Name and Team Name fields doesn't show team/project names in text box suggestions from data collected in mongoDB.

MongoDB has right data in following tables -

- collectors
- collector_items
- feature
- scope
- team

How to view the JIRA data in UI? Please find application.properties file for hygieia-feature-jira-collector -

```
# Database Name
dbname=jira_devdb
# dbname=jira_DB

# Database HostName - default is localhost
dbhost=localhost

# Database Port - default is 27017
dbport=27017

# MongoDB replicaset
dbreplicaset=false
# dbhostport=[host1:port1,host2:port2,host3:port3]

# Database Username - default is blank
dbusername=

# Database Password - default is blank
dbpassword=

# Logging File location
logging.file=./logs/jira.log

# PageSize - Expand contract this value depending on Jira implementation's
# default server timeout setting (You will likely receive a SocketTimeoutException)
feature.pageSize=100

# Delta change date that modulates the collector item task
# Occasionally, these values should be modified if database size is a concern
feature.deltaStartDate=2021-07-30T00:00:00.000000
feature.masterStartDate=2021-07-30T00:00:00.000000
feature.deltaCollectorItemStartDate=2021-07-30T00:00:00.000000

# Chron schedule: S M D M Y [Day of the Week]
feature.cron=0 * * * * *

# ST Query File Details - Required, but DO NOT MODIFY
feature.queryFolder=jiraapi-queries
feature.storyQuery=story
feature.epicQuery=epic

# JIRA CONNECTION DETAILS:
# Enterprise Proxy - ONLY INCLUDE IF YOU HAVE A PROXY
feature.jiraProxyUrl=proxy.ins.xxxxx.com
feature.jiraProxyPort=80
feature.jiraBaseUrl=https://xxxxxxxxxxx.aus.amer.xxxxxx.com/
feature.ssl.key-password=xxxxxxx
feature.jiraQueryEndpoint=rest/api/2/
# For basic authentication, requires username:password as string in base64
# This command will make this for you:  echo -n username:password | base64

feature.jiraCredentials=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

# OAuth is not fully implemented; please blank-out the OAuth values:

# feature.jiraOauthAuthtoken=
# feature.jiraOauthRefreshtoken=
# feature.jiraOauthRedirecturi=
# feature.jiraOauthExpiretime=

#############################################################################
# In Jira, general IssueType IDs are associated to various 'issue'
# attributes. However, there is one attribute which this collector's
# queries rely on that change between different instantiations of Jira.
# Please provide a string name reference to your instance's IssueType for
# the lowest level of Issues (for example, 'user story') specific to your Jira
# instance.  Note:  You can retrieve your instance's IssueType Name
# listings via the following URI:  https://[your-jira-domain-name]/rest/api/2/issuetype/
# Multiple comma-separated values can be specified.
#############################################################################
feature.jiraIssueTypeNames=Story

#############################################################################
# In Jira, your instance will have its own custom field created for 'sprint' or 'timebox' details,
# which includes a list of information.  This field allows you to specify that data field for your
# instance of Jira. Note: You can retrieve your instance's sprint data field name
# via the following URI, and look for a package name com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint;
# your custom field name describes the values in this field:
# https://[your-jira-domain-name]/rest/api/2/issue/[some-issue-name]
#############################################################################
feature.jiraSprintDataFieldName=customfield_12404-val

#############################################################################
# In Jira, your instance will have its own custom field created for 'super story' or 'epic' back-end ID,
# which includes a list of information.  This field allows you to specify that data field for your instance
# of Jira.  Note:  You can retrieve your instance's epic ID field name via the following URI where your
# queried user story issue has a super issue (for example, epic) tied to it; your custom field name describes the
# epic value you expect to see, and is the only field that does this for a given issue:
# https://[your-jira-domain-name]/rest/api/2/issue/[some-issue-name]
#############################################################################
feature.jiraEpicIdFieldName=customfield_12406-val

#############################################################################
# In Jira, your instance will have its own custom field created for 'story points'
# This field allows you to specify that data field for your instance
# of Jira.  Note:  You can retrieve your instance's storypoints ID field name via the following URI where your
# queried user story issue has story points set on it; your custom field name describes the
# story points value you expect to see:
# https://[your-jira-domain-name]/rest/api/2/issue/[some-issue-name]
#############################################################################
feature.jiraStoryPointsFieldName=customfield_12402-val

#############################################################################
# In Jira, your instance will have its own custom field created for 'team'
# This field allows you to specify that data field for your instance
# of Jira.  Note:  You can retrieve your instance's team ID field name via the following URI where your
# queried user story issue has team set on it; your custom field name describes the
# team value you expect to see:
# https://[your-jira-domain-name]/rest/api/2/issue/[some-issue-name]
#############################################################################
feature.jiraTeamFieldName=customfield_14700

# Defines how to update features per board. If true then only update based on enabled collectorItems otherwise full update
feature.collectorItemOnlyUpdate=false

#Defines the maximum number of features allow per board. If limit is reach collection will not happen for given board
feature.maxNumberOfFeaturesPerBoard=1000

# Set this to true if you use boards as team
feature.jiraBoardAsTeam=true

#Defines the number of hours between each board/team and project data refresh
feature.refreshTeamAndProjectHours=3
```

My api.properties file looks like -

```
# api.properties
dbname=jira_devdb
dbusername=
dbpassword=
dbhost=localhost
dbport=27017
dbreplicaset=false
# dbhostport=[host1:port1,host2:port2,host3:port3]
server.contextPath=/api
server.port=8000
logRequest=false
logSplunkRequest=false
# corsEnabled=false
# corsWhitelist=http://domain1.com:port,http://domain2.com:port
version.number=@application.version.number@

# auth.expirationTime=[JWT expiration time in milliseconds]
# auth.secret=[Secret Key used to validate the JWT tokens]
# auth.authenticationProviders=[Authentication types you would like to enable, defaults to STANDARD, ex: STANDARD,LDAP]
# auth.ldapServerUrl=[LDAP Server URL, including port of your LDAP server]
# auth.ldapUserDnPattern=[LDAP User Dn Pattern, where the username is replaced with '{0}']

# LDAP Server URL, including port of your LDAP server
# auth.ldapServerUrl=[ldap://company.com:389]

# If using standard LDAP
# LDAP User Dn Pattern, where the username is replaced with '{0}'
# auth.ldapUserDnPattern=[uid={0},OU=Users,dc=your,dc=company,dc=com]

# If using ActiveDirectory
# This will be the domain part of your userPrincipalName
# auth.adDomain=[company.com]
# This will be your root dn
# auth.adRootDn=[dc=your,dc=company,dc=com]
# This will be your active directory URL (required for AD)
# auth.adUrl=[Need an example]

# monitor.proxy.host=
# monitor.proxy.type=
# monitor.proxy.port=
# monitor.proxy.username=
# monitor.proxy.password=

# This will be the page size for pagination on Hygieia landing page. If this property is not set, the default value is set to 10.
pageSize=10

# API token generated for basic authentication to secure APIs.
# key=[api token]

# SSO properties with header values from UI layer
auth.userEid=[name of the header containing EID]
auth.userEmail=[name of the header containing user's email]
auth.userFirstName=[name of the header containing user's first name]
auth.userLastName=[name of the header containing user's last name]
auth.userMiddelInitials=[name of the header containing user's middle name]
auth.userDisplayName=[name of the header containing user's display name]

# Github sync api settings 

# List of not built commits
githubSyncSettings.notBuiltCommits;

# Maximum history of days to sync from current time. Default to 60 days
githubSyncSettings.firstRunHistoryDays;

# Offset time from last updated // 10 mins default
githubSyncSettings.offsetMinutes;

# Total fetch count // Default to 100
githubSyncSettings.fetchCount;

# Commits and pull sync time // Default to 86400000ms - 1 day in milliseconds
githubSyncSettings.commitPullSyncTime;
```